# What is the best way to fix laminate flooring to tiles underneath?

Tags: flooring, tile, laminate

A very "professional" builder installed laminated on top of tiles in a commercial setting. Don't ask...

The trouble is, laminate is not really fixed on the tiles and especially around the steps (only two steps), they are flexing and moving up/down slightly, which is really annoying.

My question is, what would be the best way to fix few of these laminates onto the tiles underneath? I was thinking screwing them down but I don't know if this is a good idea, what type of screws to use, whether or not I should drill it first etc..

Any ideas? If you are able to recommend some solutions please try to be specific (e.g. what type of screw I should use)..

Good luck to me!

Comment: It is common practice to install laminate flooring 'floating' so that it is not attached to the surface it rests on - so that is not the issue which needs fixing. To me, too much flex implies that the wrong underlayment was used (too thick possibly) or that the underlying surface is not flat enough (most likely).

Answer (score 1):

Modern laminate flooring is "floating", meaning you typically have an underlayment (often doubles as a vapor barrier) and then the laminate click-locks together. Finally, you add edging (base board and/or quarter round or toe nail) to lock the edges down.

Screws are NOT how you fix this. You can potentially damage the flooring doing that. Instead, it sounds like you simply have unlevel parts of your floor. What I would do is pull up sections near the unlevel parts and then use a floor leveler concrete to level the underlying tile. Then you put everything back after it's cured up solid. Should remove the "bounce"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think that is part of the problem - no underlay has been used - so this would explain the problem. Not sure if it is best to live with it or practically re-do everything..